# Display xml values with namespace - using php

Tags: php, html, xml, web

I would like to know how do I display these values from an api that returns me an xml. I've looked in some places, but it's always one without the namespace and others with namespace... but mine has both and it always bugs and doesn't display the values..

my xml:

```
<QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<TotalRows>1</TotalRows>
<Rows xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts.Documents">
<a:Document>
<a:a>6017</a:a>
<a:aa>135</a:aa>
<a:ab>-23.15749833</a:ab>
<a:ac>-45.79356167</a:ac>
<a:ad>6.80</a:ad>
<a:ai>0</a:ai>
<a:aj>Administrator</a:aj>  
<a:am>32872</a:am>
<a:an>Leonardo Righi</a:an>
<a:ao>16470252</a:ao>
<a:ap>16470108</a:ap>
<a:aq>
<a:data>
<a:key>
<a:id>d0180056-f7e6-4b13-8865-a963a9a131</a:id>
<a:tag>nomeTecnico</a:tag>
</a:key>
<a:value>Denis Rodrigues</a:value>
</a:data>
<a:ar>
<a:data>
<a:key>
<a:id>d6052d01-92b3-45a5-9059-f401eddf0ef5</a:id>
<a:tag>ImageAnswer</a:tag>
</a:key>
<a:value>27422</a:value>
</a:data>
</a:ar>
<a:b>150</a:b>
<a:bb>Manutenção Automáticas</a:bb>
<a:bc>02 - CELULARES</a:bc>
<a:bd>Cancelado</a:bd>
<a:bf>09/03/2022 14:52</a:bf>
<a:bg>11/03/2022 15:00</a:bg>
<a:bh>Automaticas</a:bh>
<a:bi>5</a:bi>
<a:bj>09/03/2022 14:41</a:bj>
<a:bk>09/03/2022 14:52</a:bk>
<a:bq>LOGISTICA LTDA</a:bq>
<a:br>2</a:br>
<a:bs>2</a:bs>
<a:bt>false</a:bt>
<a:bu>MyDocs</a:bu>
<a:bv># 1.4.17[14017]</a:bv>
<a:by>f1edqKgAgFWvOHGTmEFw42uggIDQt-K8pKPFaC6Em-Z7etzLOSr3Al6eCPndbg2</a:by>        
<a:cd>656</a:cd>
<a:ce>13235</a:ce>
<a:l>DENIS </a:l>
<a:o>f8b521e8-e92f-478e-a883</a:o>
</a:Document>
</Rows>
</QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12>
```

I tried this code, as close as I got:

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('teste.xml');
$campos = $x->
children('a', true)->
children('a', true);


foreach($campos as $chave => $valor){

echo $chave.' : '. $valor . '<br>';
    
}

?>
```

Comment: That is not valid xml. For example `<a:data>` is not closed.

Comment: in the original file there is a closure, I just reduced it to fit here.

Comment: How should we help if we don't get a working minimal reproducible example? You could provide a gist or pastebin.

Comment: done. I added the rest of the code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output given your sample xml.

Comment: I would like to display the above xml in a list

Comment: one under the other

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the children by giving the namespace or its prefix. I prefer the prefix, because it is shorter.

Demo (previous): https://3v4l.org/VNt5d
Demo (recursive): https://3v4l.org/uelMs

#### Note

Your data is still invalid. `<a:aq>` is not closed. So I removed it for my answer!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlText);

function printKeyValue(string $key, SimpleXMLElement $value): void {
    echo "$key: ";
    if ($children = $value->children('a', true)) {
        foreach($children as $childKey => $childValue) {
            printKeyValue($childKey, $childValue);
        }
        return;
    }
    echo "$value\n";
};

foreach($xml->Rows->children('a', true) as $document) {
    foreach($document as $key => $value) {
        printKeyValue($key, $value);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
a: 6017
aa: 135
ab: -23.15749833
ac: -45.79356167
ad: 6.80
ai: 0
aj: Administrator
am: 32872
an: Leonardo Righi
ao: 16470252
ap: 16470108
data: key: id: d0180056-f7e6-4b13-8865-a963a9a131
tag: nomeTecnico
value: Denis Rodrigues
ar: data: key: id: d6052d01-92b3-45a5-9059-f401eddf0ef5
tag: ImageAnswer
value: 27422
b: 150
bb: Manutenção Automáticas
bc: 02 - CELULARES
bd: Cancelado
bf: 09/03/2022 14:52
bg: 11/03/2022 15:00
bh: Automaticas
bi: 5
bj: 09/03/2022 14:41
bk: 09/03/2022 14:52
bq: LOGISTICA LTDA
br: 2
bs: 2
bt: false
bu: MyDocs
bv: # 1.4.17[14017]
by: f1edqKgAgFWvOHGTmEFw42uggIDQt-K8pKPFaC6Em-Z7etzLOSr3Al6eCPndbg2
cd: 656
ce: 13235
l: DENIS 
o: f8b521e8-e92f-478e-a883
```

Comment: Prefixes are not fixed, but namespace URIs are. Just put the namespace URIs into constants/variables to avoid repeating them.

Comment: thank you so much. For me it worked. I just couldn't get the information that is inside the <a:data>

Comment: No problem. You can either use recursive output (see answer updated) or do a special handling like `if ('data' === $key) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake the namespaces prefixes with the actual namespace. The namespace definitions are the `xmlns`/`xmlns:*` attributes. Prefixes are optional for element nodes. The document element should be read as `{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts}QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12`. Here are 3 examples that all resolve to this:

- `<QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts">`
- `<q:QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12 xmlns:q="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts">`
- `<qtable:QTableGridDataSourceForMobileOfDocumentWBuH9k12 xmlns:qtable="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts">`

Namespaces can be redefined on any element node. So a prefix will only be valid until redefined. That makes it a really bad idea to rely on the prefixes in the document. Always use the namespace URI and/or define your own prefixes.

SimpleXML does some implicit namespace handling in the background - like using the default namespace of the current context node. The explicit variant would look like this:

```
const XMLNS_CONTRACTS = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts';
const XMLNS_DOCUMENT = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts.Documents';

$qTable = simplexml_load_string(getXMLString());

foreach($qTable->children(XMLNS_CONTRACTS)->Rows->children(XMLNS_DOCUMENT) as $document) {
    foreach($document as $key => $value) {
        var_dump([$key, (string)$value]);
    }
}
```

Or with DOM and Xpath:

Take note that the example uses its own prefixes for the Xpath expressions. It only depends on the namespace URIs.

```
const XMLNS_CONTRACTS = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts';
const XMLNS_DOCUMENT = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sinfic.DataContracts.Documents';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('c', XMLNS_CONTRACTS);
$xpath->registerNamespace('d', XMLNS_DOCUMENT);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//c:Rows/d:Document') as $rowsDocument) {
    foreach($xpath->evaluate('./d:*', $rowsDocument) as $cell) {
        var_dump(
            [$cell->localName, $cell->textContent]
        );
    }
}
```

The XML format is not a good one *imho* - so it might feel annoying to use. XML tags are supposed to be fixed and semantic. Dynamic tag names a big no go.